# Yii: Using CDbCriteria with custom variable in model

Tags: yii

I'm trying to search based on full_name, which is a concatenation of first_name and last_name, but I keep getting an error.

This is what my controller looks like:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addSearchCondition('full_name',$customer_search);
$customers = Customer::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

In my Customer model, I have a method that should return the full_name:

```
public function getFull_name() {
  return $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
}
```

But, I get this error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `customer` `t` WHERE full_name LIKE :ycp0
```

I need to be able to search both the first_name and last_name, what do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: Will the user be entering the full name, or part names in `$customer_search`? i.e do you want them to be able to search for 'John Smith' and return all 'John Smiths', or will the user be searching for 'John' and you want to return all people with first or last name 'John'?

Comment: I'd like them to enter either a portion of the first or last name and have it return results.  So, if they entered in 'ev', it would pull up 'Steve Smith' and 'Bob Stevens', for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use "calculated" columns in your query. You will simply have to rewrite the criteria so that they only check columns that physically exist in the database.

Since you want to find people where *part* of *either* their first or last name matches you will have to enclose the search term in percent signs (see MySql documentation for [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)) and specify the second condition with `OR`:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addSearchCondition('first_name', $customer_search);
$criteria->addSearchCondition('last_name', $customer_search, true, "OR");
$customers = Customer::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: Do you mind providing an example of what I need to do?  I understand the full_name column doesn't exist in the database, so what do I need to do differently?

Comment: That did the trick...thank you.  BTW, I removed the wildcards, since they are added by default when you use addSearchCondition().  So my final result is:             `$criteria->addSearchCondition('first_name',$customer_search);
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('last_name',$customer_search,true,'OR');`

Comment: @ews2001: Glad to help. I edited the answer to remove them, thanks for pointing that out.